# Django differentiate between the first time user and returning user

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using django registration redux for login and auth purposes. I want to do the following.

1. if the user logs in for the first time i want to redirect to URL-"profile/create"
2. if the user is a returning user i dont want the user to access the URL-"profile/create" and i want the user to be redirected to another URL.

Comment: what do u mean by returning user

Comment: a user is logging in for the second time to the app.

Comment: after login you can check if profile is created then return on another url otherwise return to profile url

Answer (score 0):

`django-registration-redux` seems to use Django's [login-view](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration/blob/f9aa6be116e4dff1a2b197ab11349cda9731d37b/registration/auth_urls.py#L32) for logging users in per default.

Thus I would provide a customized login view instead that additionally inspects the user that tries to log in and checks if [`last_login`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c651331b34b7c3841c126959e6e52879bc6f0834/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L50) is already filled out.

Depending on the result the user then can be redirected to the desired page once the authentication succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

in most basic form when user login first time it has to be registered.
do not use this kind of functionality at login use it at register function (view)

this is a old draft code that give you the idea

```
def ragister(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile-settings/')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        fname = request.POST['fname']
        lname = request.POST['lname']
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        users = User()
        users.password = password
        users.username = username
        users.first_name = fname
        users.last_name = lname

        try:
            users.set_password(password)
            users.save()
            users = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if users is not None:
                login(request,users)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile-settings/')
            messages.success(request, "This number is registered please try other number or reset your password")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/register/')
```