# How to redirect a user to a different page if he's logging in for the first time after registration in django?

Tags: python, django, django-login

I have created a **Getting Started** page to which I have to send the users if they are logging in for the first time after registration.

I also referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174408/django-differentiate-between-the-first-time-user-and-returning-user) but didn't understand anything

If not I have to redirect them to the **Home** page.

I have set the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL to 'home' in settings.py

I have not tried anything yet because I have no idea about how I should do it. Please assume a simple html for both the pages with an `<h1>` tag containing their respective names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, and this are three that I usually do:

1. you can put additional field in user model, for example seen_getting_started that is boolean and during processing of home template in views.py you can check for this field and redirect accordingly to getting started page. I have an option that user needs to select his language and date formats, so if it not changed and stored in his profile than "select language and date format" page pops out
2. you could also check his creation time, if it is created in last 10 minutes it is safe to assume that the user is new, but there might be some issues with that if you use for example mail check during registration
3. if you are using mail check during registration, than you need to lend user on "email confirmed" page that could also lead to your getting started page.

Hope it helps. Sure that other options might work too.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please tell me how I should implement the first point. I understood what I have to do but how should I do it?

Comment: If you are going to extend Djagno buil-in User model, you need to extend it to be able to add fields. This article can help: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html